# How to define a different layout for each physical keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

It appears that the solution may need to define different layout, one per keyboard.

I have a laptop with an included physical keyboard; I am adding a bluetooth keypad; some keys of the keypad won't behave correctly. For example, **$=>4** , **( => 9** , **) => 0** ,  **, => ;**

I have been thinking about defining keybondings, but this failed long time ago. So, it could be a better idea to define one layout for each physical keyboard. If possible.

Linux Debian bullseye
Enlightenment 17
Dell Latitude E6430

Bluetooth keyboard appears here:

```
    ↳ Bluetooth Keyboard System Control         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Bluetooth Keyboard                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Bluetooth Keyboard Consumer Control       id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Main keyboard is FR.